# How do I add number to Array? Swift

Tags: swift

For example:

```
var myArray = ["first string","second string"]

myArray.append(35) // Here will be an error
```

Comment: I think Apple has some nice documentation about this. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Comment: Your array is of type `[String]`, with elements of type `String`. Hence, swift expects new members of the array to be, also, of type `String`, whereas `35` above is an integer literal. Try `myArray.append("35")` or `myArray.append(String(35) ?? "")`.

Comment: I`m just learning swift, and I want to know - is it possible to add number to array if it has type of STRING ?

Comment: Type the array to be more generic, `[Any]`, I believe, and you can append 35. But this way you lose type information.

Answer (score 2):

If you *Option-click* on `myArray`, you will see that it is of type `[String]` (array of `String`).  You can only add `String`s to `myArray`.

If you want to be able to add `Int` to your array, you will need a more inclusive type.  If you make your array `[Any]`, you can put anything in it.

```
var myArray:[Any] = ["first string","second string"]
myArray.append(35)   // This now works
```

If you want to store only `Int` and `String`, you can create your own custom protocol:

```
protocol StringsAndInts {
}

extension String: StringsAndInts {
}

extension Int: StringsAndInts {
}

var myArray:[StringsAndInts] = ["first string","second string"]

myArray.append(35)

print(myArray)  // ["first string", "second string", 35]

myArray.append(3.14)  // error: argument type 'Double' does not conform to expected type 'StringsAndInts'
```

Answer (score 1):

If you write

```
var myArray = ["first string","second string"]
print(myArray.dynamicType)
```

You will see that `myArray` is of type `Array<String>` or `[String]`. You cannot append an `Int` to that.

What you need to do is specify the type of the `myArray` yourself:

```
var myArray : [AnyObject] = ["first string","second string"]

print(myArray.dynamicType) // now prints Array<AnyObject> which you can add Int to

myArray.append(35)
```

Comment: Thanks! It is exactly what I1m looking for )

Comment: If you want to allow *only* Int and String in the array take a look at the answer by vacawama!

Comment: luk2302 please, note that this works only with help of free bridging, so import Foundation is necessary.  String is bridged to _NSContiguousString
and Int to __NSCFNumber.